# Listening for Firebase Analytics automatic events

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

Firebase has the functionality to [track several events automatically](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485?hl=en&ref_topic=6317484). This means your application code is never actually executed and the SDK takes care of pushing the events to your Firebase project.

I need a way to *listen* to the automatically tracked events, so that I can send them to a different analytics service.

I check the firebase documentation [(1)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/package-summary) [(2)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/start/) and I didn't find anything related to this.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the firebase-comunity slack team:

[image]